# Vista to windows 7 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, licensing, windows-vista, upgrade

I am planning to upgrade from Windows vista business to windows 7 home. Can I perform a format on the system disk, boot from the installation DVD, and install the OS on it with it still having a valid license key? Is the OEM vista license key is valid for windows 7 and if so how to preserve it? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upgrade to a different SKU i.e
 business to home, and you can't use a Vista licence on Windows 7. What I would recommend is buying a Windows 10 licence, then backup your documents etc, do a clean install of Windows 10 and copy you Documents back to the new installation.